# Ignoring country-specific decimal separator

Tags: c#

I'm currently doing an app, that needs to be able to work with the US number layout (`123,456.78`) as well as with the German layout (`123.456,78`).

Now my approach is to use NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo about like this:

```
temp = temp.ToString(NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
```

this works great when for example reading a number from a textbox. When System is set to English format it will take the `.` as separator, when it's set to German it will use the `,`.

So far so good....but here's the problem: I have a device that returns info in the American format, and that won't change (transmitted via RS232). So I receive something like `10.543355E-00`.

Now when on German setting the `.` will be discarded since it's just the group separator 
and the number I will end up with is 10543355....which is a lot more :)

I tried with the same technique thinking this would make the whole thing kind of 'cultureless' to be able to process it independently from the system language but it didn't work :)

I hope you can maybe help me here...I'd love to use a way without having to implement the whole culture stuff etc since all I need here is really numbers that get calculated the right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx) when parsing strings from the device.  This will cause it to use the invariant culture, which has the US rules for decimal separation.

---

Edit in response to comments:

The issue is not when you call `.ToString()`, but rather when you read the string from the device, and convert it to a number:

```
string inputFromRS232Device = GetDeviceInput();
double value;

// You need this when converting to the double - not when calling ToString()
bool success = double.TryParse(
                          inputFromRS232Device, 
                          NumberStyles.Float, 
                          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                          out value);
```

Comment: using this the same way as mentioned above (.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)) won't make any difference....   Thanks for the fast answer though